# How i can POST multiple action in dropdown list to node js?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I stucked multiple action's in a single form(dropdown list). I can POST only a single action.

**admin.html**

```
<form action="/start" method="post" id="tableForm">
  <select id="myselect" size="5">
    <optgroup label="Select docker commands here">
      <option name="" value="0"></option>
      <option name="table1" value="1">docker start</option>
      <option name="table2" value="2">docker build</option>
      <option name="table3" value="3">docker run</option>
      <option name="table4" value="4">docker pull</option>
      <option name="table5" value="5">docker stop</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

**server.js**

```
app.post('/start', function(req, resp) {
  console.log('hello');
});
app.post('/stop', function(req, resp) {
  console.log('morning');
});
app.post('/build', function(req, resp) {
  console.log('Have a nice day ');
});
```

I want to POST multiple action in single form in a dropdown list. I can't call back from server POST request in admin.html(/stop,/build).

any one suggest?

Comment: You can use Ajax request if you want to request more than one url

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to select multiple options and post them, add the `multiple` keyword to the `select`.

```
<form action="/start" method="post" id="tableForm">
  <select id="myselect" size="5" multiple>
    <optgroup label="Select docker commands here">
      <option name="" value="0"></option>
      <option name="table1" value="1">docker start</option>
      <option name="table2" value="2">docker build</option>
      <option name="table3" value="3">docker run</option>
      <option name="table4" value="4">docker pull</option>
      <option name="table5" value="5">docker stop</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp